# Django Свой декоратор проверки на авторизованность. AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, аутентификация, декоратор

написал свой декоратор, для проверки на авторизацию так как нужно получать именно request, а не request.user, и проверять наличие данных в сессии request-а:

```
def login_required(func=is_authenticated, redirect_url="/"):
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if func(request):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(redirect_url)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Если в представлениях(контроллерах)

```
@login_required(is_authenticated)
def start(request)
...
```

В вызове декоратора указывать конкретную функцию проверки(ту же что по умолчанию), то всё работает.
Если же иначе:

```
@login_required
def start(request)
...
```

Выбрасывается исключение:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/start/

Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['web',
 'bootstrap4',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/mister/Рабочий стол/COMPANY/PROJECT/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/mister/Рабочий стол/COMPANY/PROJECT/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  97.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "/home/mister/Рабочий стол/COMPANY/PROJECT/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /start/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Прошу подсказать с чем связанно такое поведение и как решить эту проблему, если есть такая возможность, не указывая функцию проверки декоратору при каждом вызове

**P.S. В python&&django совсем недавно, так что если это очень простой вопрос, прошу тапками не кидать, я искал и искал, но так и не смог разобраться**

Comment: запись `@login_required(is_authenticated)` приведет к следующему `login_required(is_authenticated)(start)`. второй вариант `@login_required` приведет к `login_required(start)`.  Добавьте скобки `@login_required()`.

Comment: @godva не могли бы подсказать где об этом можно прочитать? прямая ссылка была бы очень кстати :) Спасибо за совет, опробую как доберусь до ПК

Comment: [pep-318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax)

Comment: @godva добавьте ваш комментарий с ссылкой, на доку, отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись `@login_required(is_authenticated)` приведет к следующему `login_required(is_authenticated)(start)`. Второй вариант `@login_required приведет к login_required(start)`. Добавьте скобки `@login_required()`. Подробнее о синтаксисе декораторов читать в [pep-318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax).